# need help to check sin result doesnt match, using taylor series in python

Tags: python, trigonometry, taylor-series

this is my code:

```
def faktorial(z):
    a=1
    for x in range (1,z+1):
        a=a*x
    return a
def sin(x):
    p=0
    for k in range(0,1000):
        a=((-1)**k)
        b=((x**(2*k+1)))
        c=(faktorial((2*k)+1))
        p+=(a*b)/c #sin x
    return p
x=45
print(sin(x))
```

but when it run the result doesnt match, sin(45) supposed be 0,850904 but my progrom get 37.93452 as a result.thx[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afjd6.png)

Comment: Shouldn't sin(45) be 1/sqrt(2)? Assuming 45 is in degrees, not radians.

Comment: I think it some kind of overflow/rounding error. Try using 10 instead of 1000 in your range, and use lower numbers, not numbers like 45 radians

Comment: as an aside, you can use `*=` to multiply by and assign a value to a variable, i.e. `x = 5` followed by `x *= 10` will make `x = 50`

Comment: @Stefan aahhh i got it i misunderstood the taylor series, i thought its using radians instead of degress. and i try to change the range and its work now. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

you get a wrong answer because you use degree instead of radian . Also this approximation is correct when your x is too close to 0 .

Comment: yeah i misunderstood the taylor series, i thought its using radians instead of degress. sorry i post wrong assumtion, because i I've not studied this series yet. but i only got the formula for my tasks, so sorry i make wrong assumsition.

Answer (score 0):

The taylor series is calculated for the angle in terms of radians, to use it you must convert from degree to radian.

So either you can change the units in your input or convert from degrees to degree.

from math import pi

```
def sin(x):
    # Either do this
    x = x*pi/180
    p=0
    for k in range(0,1000):
        a=((-1)**k)
        b=((x**(2*k+1)))
        c=(faktorial((2*k)+1))
        p+=(a*b)/c #sin x
    return p
# or this x=pi/4
x = 45
print(sin(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid rounding errors by using fewer terms, and lower numbers in radians:

```
def faktorial(z):
   a=1
   for x in range (1,z+1):
       a=a*x
   return a
def sin(x):
    p=0
    for k in range(0,10):
        a=((-1)**k)
        b=((x**(2*k+1)))
        c=(faktorial((2*k)+1))
        p+=(a*b)/c #sin x
    return p
x=3.1415/4
print(sin(x))
```